# ASP.NET MVC is there an attribute for a ViewModel/Dto property which causes the modelbinder/view to ignore it?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a property in a dto that I don't want the modelbinder/view to use the get on? Is there an attribute I can decorate it with to stop them from interrogating it?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public class Model
{
  [Bindable(false)] // this is the attribute you can use...
  public int ModelId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: It still tries to validate the property as if it was binding.

Answer (score 0):

See the "Include" and "Exclude" properties on the BindAttribute:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.bindattribute_members.aspx